# Load JSON file in Python without the 'u in the key

Tags: python, json

I was doing some work in Python with graphs and wanted to a save some structures in files so I could load them fast when I resumed work. One of those was a dictionary which I saved in JSON format using json.dump.

When I load it back with json.load the keys have changed from "1" to u'1'. Why is that? What does it mean? How can I change it? I use the keys later to make some lists which I will then use with the original graph which nodes are the keys (in integer form) and it causes problem in comparisons...

Comment: Not sure this is really a question the strings loaded in JSON are unicode so the u'1' = '1' to prove that try u'1' == '1' in your interpreter.  You should be able to manipulate the objects without any problem  to change them back just int(key) and it will return your integer

Comment: hmmm, then I might have been doing something else wrong... THanks for the clarification all of you guys.

Answer (score 3):

The u'' or u"" just means that this is a unicode string. Which in general should not be any problem unless you need a byte string. Though I would expect that your original data already was unicode, so it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

The `u` prefix signifies a Unicode string. In Python 2.x, you can convert it to a regular string with `str()`. That shouldn't really be necessary, though; `u'1' == '1'` because Python will do any conversion for you before comparing.

Comment: `str()` would implicitly encode the unicode value with ASCII; better to use `.encode('utf8')`; e.g. explicitly encode, *but only if you really need a byte string*.

Comment: Given that the original input was supposedly byte strings, I assumed the round-trip would be safe; but of course, you are right, as usual.

Answer (score 0):

It is a unicode string. You can treat it as a normal python string in most cases. If you really want to convert it to a normal string use *str()*. If you need to convert it to a *bytes* type, use *object.encode(encoding)* where encoding is the encoding of the Unicode character, usually *'utf-8'*.